# How to redirect to an external url from spring mvc controller?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

This is my code inside the controller class. When the user enters localhost:8080/url, it retrieves the original long url let's say www.google.com saved in the database and then i want it to redirect to www.google.com but instead it redirects to localhost:8080/www.google.com and thus gives en error 500.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/{url}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public RedirectView getLongURl(@PathVariable("url") String url) {

        String original = database.getLongUrl(UrlShortener.decode(url));
        RedirectView redirectview = new RedirectView();
        redirectview.setUrl(original);
        return redirectview;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return a ModelAndView

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/{url}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView method(@PathVariable("url") String url) {
        String original = database.getLongUrl(UrlShortener.decode(url));
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + original);
    }
```

You do not have the option to redirect your request to an outside domain/host like google.com using the RedirectView. As it's name says, it redirects your request to an "another view" in your application.
Refer the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html) for more on RedirectView